# Using IsValid function to validate text

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I' am using IsValid [here is the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_in-k_37.html). Below is the code where am trying to validate only text and space in the textfield with ColdFusion.

Well this doesn't work, what am missing here or is their any other function available for easy use. It should allow only alphabetical and space

```
  <cfif isdefined("Form.txtname") 
        and Form.txtname eq "" 
        or Form.txtname eq "Enter your name" 
        or FindNoCase("http://",Form.txtname) neq 0 
        or IsValid("regex", Form.txtname, "[A-Z][a-z] +") eq 1>
```

Comment: You should probably be accepting https URLs as well as http ones.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to validate only alphabetical text and spaces, your regex should be

```
^[a-zA-Z ]*$
```

- the `*` will allow empty textfield (so no need for `eq ""` anymore)
- `^$` are anchors, that match respectively the beginning and the end of the string. They make sure there's *only* what you want in the textfield.

Comment: Since empty string is allowed, this could use `*` and the earlier check for `eq ""` could then be removed.